Accessing and overwriting builtin variables or classes within a webpage using a firefox addon's content script (Or alternative method?)
I wrote a userscript a while back for a specific webpage and I want to make a more polished tool using a web extension.
The general idea is, Im intercepting a webpage's builtin Class, and rewriting one of it's common functions to be able to access a variable I need. I then need to make use of that variable to complete a function and output some information. (In this case, accessing scene from inside a JSC3D instance, so I can download the model being rendered)
The script is really quite simple when injected as a userscript:
// @grant unsafeWindow

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Intercept function, extract active Scene variable's current state during runtime, 
    // and send it back to the window's global context
    JSC3D.Scene.prototype.getChild = function (a) {
        unsafeWindow.scene = this;
        return this.children[a]; // business as usual / sustain default behavior
    };

    unsafeWindow.downloadStl = function() { /* .. do stuff with scene variable here .. */ }

    downloadStl(); // can call from anywhere if you use unsafeWindow
}

Now, this works fine inside of a userscript, Ive been able to do what I want with it without any issues. Heres the complete userscript for reference: https://gist.github.com/MisterSirCode/8342aff651c10f5f81d70a75ba2469df
My issue now is that I seemingly cant convert this into an extension to make it more accessible / easier to maintain and publish.
Inside my content script, I can access and log the current tab's window instance, and I can see in the browser's console that JSC3D is defined and accessible there. However, within the context of my content script, I don't even have access to read that class, let alone overwrite it or it's prototype.
So I'm out of ideas here. Would it be better for me to use a different type of script within the extension that may have access to these variables? Or is there a method to do this with content scripts that Im just missing..
Ive been struggling to find a solution to do this for the past few hours. Looking online I seemingly cant find anything that isn't 10 years old and using outdated code that no longer works (For example, the stackoverflow and stackexchange questions talking about using APIs such as window.top.getBrowser() and other similar functions, which arent defined at all on my end), or tools for converting userscripts to extensions that are long abandoned / non-functional.
I'm not even sure if using a content script here is the best choice, but with the incomplete documentation I don't really know what else to use. Background scripts I couldn't seem to get access to the tabs API, and ultimately couldnt read or execute any code on any webpage. I also saw that extensions could directly use their own userscripts, but the API doesn't actually explain how to connect one to a webpage. Or, at the very least, I didn't understand what it was saying to do.

Use wrappedJSObject + exportFunction, more info.
